# INNER JOIN problems

Tags: sql, vb6

I tried to make a code on VB6, but it seems an error occured...
can you help me master?

Here's my code :

```
"SELECT guru.nip, guru.nama_guru, set_hr_kerja.bulan, set_jam_kerja.hari, set_hr_kerja.jlh_kerja, set_jam_kerja.jam_masuk " & _
"FROM (guru INNER JOIN set_hr_kerja ON guru.nip = set_hr_kerja.nip) INNER JOIN set_jam_kerja ON guru.nip = set_jam_kerja.nip " & _
"WHERE " & _
"nama_guru LIKE '%" & Kutip(TBox(Index).Text) & "%' OR " & _
"hari LIKE '%" & sHari & "%' " & _
"ORDER BY nama_guru")
```

The Error says : "ODBC driver does not support the requested properties" and also when I press
debug button an error "Operation is not allowed when object is closed"

What should I do? Can you help me?
I'm glad if you can help me...
Thanks

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code please. Particularly where you execute the sql.

Comment: "SELECT guru.nip, guru.nama_guru, set_hr_kerja.bulan, set_jam_kerja.hari, set_hr_kerja.jlh_kerja, set_jam_kerja.jam_masuk " & _
"FROM (guru INNER JOIN set_hr_kerja ON guru.nip = set_hr_kerja.nip) INNER JOIN set_jam_kerja ON guru.nip = set_jam_kerja.nip " & _
"WHERE " & _
"nama_guru LIKE '%" & Kutip(TBox(Index).Text) & "%' OR " & _
"hari LIKE '%" & sHari & "%' " & _
"ORDER BY nama_guru")

Comment: So how are you passing that SQL to your database?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your statement. The parenthesis after the FROM are incorrect and not really needed either.

```
"SELECT guru.nip, guru.nama_guru, set_hr_kerja.bulan, set_jam_kerja.hari, set_hr_kerja.jlh_kerja, set_jam_kerja.jam_masuk " & _
"FROM guru INNER JOIN set_hr_kerja ON guru.nip = set_hr_kerja.nip) INNER JOIN set_jam_kerja ON guru.nip = set_jam_kerja.nip " & _
"WHERE " & _
"nama_guru LIKE '%" & Kutip(TBox(Index).Text) & "%' OR " & _
"hari LIKE '%" & sHari & "%' " & _
"ORDER BY nama_guru"
```